# BAD_ACCESS with strcpy in shared memory (C)

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy

I'm very new here and German, so please excuse my bad English here.
As a part of a school exercise we are supposed to implement a socket server with a shared memory for a key-value-store, running on an UNIX-based system. The server, the shared memory and the fork() are working. We use an array of structs and we made functions for this (put, get, delete). In the put-method we get this BAD_ACCESS, when we copy two strings. 
Code of the method is below, the link to our repository is here: [Github Repo](https://github.com/marvinworks/BS1SS17KlimmStrutzWolf)

```
int put(int key, char *value, char *resp){
int emptyIndex = -1;
//strcpy(resp, "");
resp = "";
for(int i = 0; i < STORELENGTH; i++){
    // If the key exists, overwrite it, give back previous value, and return true
    if(kv[i].key == key) {
        resp = kv[i].value;
        kv[i].value = value;
        return 1;
    }
    // If the key doesn't exist, remember the empty index
    if(kv[i].key == NULL){
        emptyIndex = i;
    }
}

// If there was an empty index, just reuse it
if(emptyIndex > -1) {
    kv[emptyIndex].key = key;
    resp = "";
    kv[emptyIndex].value = value;
    return 1;
}

*resp = (char) "Error: Put was not successful.";
return -1;
}
```

As you see, the strcpy-Function is a comment, because the programm immediatly stopped working. 
Thanks for your help,
Alex

Comment: What do you think `*resp = (char) "Error: Put was not successful."` would accomplish? That casting should be a hint that you're doing something wrong, don't silence compiler warnings by just blind casting.

Comment: As for your problem, what *is* `resp`? What do you pass to the function? How do you call it? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Parameters in C are passed by value, not reference. Assigning a new value to `resp` is pointless if you return immediately thereafter. You seem to be confused about what the purpose of `rest` is.

Comment: At the point you call `strcpy(resp, "");`, you have not done anything to protect against `resp` being NULL.  Also, if the pointer passed in is uninitialized, bad things like this happen.  Make sure the argument  passed in points to/is a valid memory location big enough to hold your string.  Then check for NULL in the function, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that **resp** should be a string in your `main.c` you are initializing the it incorrectly:

```
char *resp = ""; <- This one is bad
//char resp[BUFSIZ]; <-- This one is good but commented.
```

As a result you have a `resp` being an char* with allocated size of 1. While `strcpy` needs at least size of 2 - one for "" you copy one for "\0" - the string termination character. That's why your app crashes when you try put the length of 2 in the **resp** whose length is 1 - you are trying to write to the memory you don't own.

Also instead of:

```
*resp = (char) "Error: Put was not successful.";
```

You should use the `strcpy` also. I would suggest following:

**1. Read about the arrays and pointers to understand it better**

**2. Read documentation for functions you are using if they are new to you, like [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).** It contains some valuable info like:

> To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination shall
>   be long enough to contain the same C string as source (**including the
>   terminating null character**), and should not overlap in memory with
>   source.

**3. Learn about debugging - imho, it's one of the most important things!**
For example [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory-Allocation.html#Memory-Allocation) describes some points of memory allocation and debugging techniques.

All this could make your life easier in future :)